# How to create monthly approved reports using PowerBI reports? - General Question

Tags: powerbi, powerapps, power-automate

I am trying to understand the best way of creating a monthly report which will be looking for the previous month's data and allow approvers to enter their comments and approve each slicer (location) in the filter section. I have PowerBI reports which already set and have the data I need. What would be the best approach to take allowing users (there is a user permission list in excel which look for each user's location and approval location) to enter their comments and approve each location? I was thinking of using the PowerBI report as my source and running power automate flows for running approvals in power apps. Any suggestions?

Comment: This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear? It rather looks like someone is cheating ...